# Deleting posts with 3 down-votes (but answers provided) for getting "Peer Pressure" badge

Tags: discussion, downvotes, badges, post-ban

Badge `Peer Pressure` says: "*Delete own post with score of -3 or lower*".

Is it allowed to delete my own post with 3 down-votes if some answers are provided?

Will I get a post-ban for it?

By the way, there are posts spilling light on this post-ban issue but there's no references about such badges as `Peer Pressure`.

Comment: if you want that badge urgently, just ask a PHP question where you use any of the `mysql_` functions. Guaranteed down votes, delete question when at -3. Profit.

Comment: Nice remark))))

Comment: You could undelete it after getting the badge.

Comment: I think you get it for answers too - providing completely unrelated/awful  answer should be easier and less dramatic from ban point of view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are multiple answers, or any answer with a positive score, you won't be *able* to delete the question.

If you make a habit of deleting negatively scored answered questions you could end up being banned from asking questions, yes, but it wouldn't happen as a result of a single post being deleted; there would need to be other negative contributions to the site as well for that to happen.

Comment: Minor quibble with the wording..... `If you make a habit of deleting negatively scored answered questions you could end up being banned from asking question` seems to suggest that deleting is the driver behind the post ban, when it is the asking of the poor questions to begin with that is bigger reason behind any ban

Comment: @psubsee2003 Both are factors.  It's been specifically stated that they don't want people asking acceptable questions and then deleting them as soon as they're answered.

Answer (score 5):

You more than likely should not delete a question that other members have taken the time to answer for the sake of a badge (and a bronze one at that). You will be unable to delete if any of the answers are upvoted.

Comment: Whether or not he *should* delete it is dependant on the specifics of the question, and whether or not it actually has potential value to others.  If the question is entirely localized to him, it is a poor question that has attracted a non-answer, etc. then it would actually be *beneficial* to delete it, so long as it's something that you don't make a pattern out of.